# Httpfile sendrequest -> formatting requestbody?

Tags: c++, mfc

So basically I can do GET- Webrequests, which only require 2 headers and it works perfectly (I get return code 200), example below:

```
.
.
.
saHeaders.Append("authorization: (accesstoken)\n");
saHeaders.Append("id: (id)\n");

pFile->AddRequestHeaders(sHeaders); // szHeaders);
pFile->SendRequest();
.
.
```

So now for a post request, I would have to have 3 headers, and then add a request body, but I dont know how to properly format it.
One required parameter would be specified like:

```
name: Test
```

So the request now looks like this, status code is still 400, in TCHAR sz i tried also different formats, like

```
name: "Test", or 
name= Test
```

..etc.

```
saHeaders.Append("authorization: (accesstoken)\n");                       //Header 1
saHeaders.Append("id: (id)\n");                                           //Header 2
saHeaders.Append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\n");      //Header 3

TCHAR sz[] =_T("name: TEST");


CString strServerName = sServer;
DWORD dwRequestFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT;

        pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort);
        pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, sObject, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, dwRequestFlags);
        pFile->AddRequestHeaders(saHeaders);
        pFile->SendRequest(NULL, 0, sz, lstrlen(sz));
        pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
```

Comment: Request Body is not Header

Comment: where to put the body then? into openrequest()? sendreqest()? I cant find where to put it anywhere!

Comment: Write into [GetRequestStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_GetRequestStream)

Comment: [CHttpFile::SendRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/chttpfile-class?view=vs-2019#sendrequest): *"`lpOptional`: Any optional data to send immediately after the request headers. This is generally used for POST and PUT operations."* @tho: This is MFC, not .NET.

Comment: Regardless, we need to see a [mcve]. For one, we don't know how you got your `CHttpFile`.

Comment: I posted a answer here with updated code, still not working :/

Comment: fixed, its in first post now!

Comment: You promise to send JSON formatted data, but aren't sending JSON formatted data. That's unlikely to be successful. JSON formatted data would look like this: `"{\"name\": \"test\"}"`.

Comment: it works now! I can not tell you how often i actually used this formatting and it failed ,s o something was off. I updated my post with working code!

Comment: im sorry, I fixed it and will watch out in future posts!

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

It works now! It has to be formatted like so:

```
saHeaders.Append("authorization: (accesstoken)\n");                       //Header 1
saHeaders.Append("id: (id)\n");                                           //Header 2
saHeaders.Append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\n");      //Header 3

TCHAR sz[] =_T("{\n\"name\": \"TEST\"\n}");


CString strServerName = sServer;
DWORD dwRequestFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT;

        pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort);
        pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, sObject, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, dwRequestFlags);
        //pFile->AddRequestHeaders(saHeaders);
        pFile->SendRequest(sHeaders, sz, lstrlen(sz));   //Headers can also be added in previous line, and be NULL params in sendrequest
        pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
```